# probability theory of repeating experiments

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Lets say you have an experiment which succeeds in giving you the right answer with probability p. Lets say you repeat this experiment twice. We can conclude that at least one of them succeeded with probability $(1-(1-p)^2).$ This seems very intuitive but couldnt it be possible that there some some sort of interference or joint force between the two experiments that drives the probability to higher than $(1-(1-p)^2)$? Also couldnt we generalize this by saying run 100 experiments, couldnt the same logic imply?

Comment: If you ask $100$ weather forecasters who were all trained the same way and use the same computer with the same input data, they may all make correct predictions at identical times, and at other times make identical errors.  Or at least their errors may be correlated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you need is *independence.* Two events are called independent if the probability of them occurring simultaneously is the product of their individual probabilities.

If you are tossing a coin (even an unfair one with $p>1/2$) then the probability of tossing "heads" is not influenced by what you tossed last time, so the probability of tossing "heads" twice in a row is $p^2.$

That might be different in a different experimental setup.